# Do datalakes offered from amazon and azure support rosbag files?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, data-lake

I have a lot of camera, radar and lidar data stored with me in a hard-disk in rosbag formats. I would now like to shift this to a cloud service, preferably trying to preserve the rosbag format.

From what I understand in data lakes you can store data in their natural format. Is there a also limit the formats supported by datalakes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Both Azure Storage as well as AWS S3 are object stores. You can put in files in whatever native format in there. I am not aware of any limit in terms of file formats in either of those.

Answer (score 0):

Data Lake gives the freedom to store data in natural format. So far there is no limit, in whatever format you can store data in data lake.

Aws Datalake documents
https://aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/

Azure Datalake
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/data-lake/